# I am searching for a short story about ongoing conflict in the middle east 500 years from the present

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence, military-sf

It likely appeared in an anthology, such as one of Gardner Dozois' or from an issue of Asimov's. The most compelling features of the story were:

1. The conflict in the Middle East is still going on 500 years from now.
2. The militaries of both sides made heavy and increasing use of artificial intelligence for their military strategy.
3. It was discovered that the war, at this point, was basically a game of chess played between two artificial intelligences with human lives as the pieces.

The story helped illustrate how utterly stupid war is in the first place by pointing out that all the lives fed into this scenario were just chewed up for "the machine". Although artificial intelligence computers were literal machines in the story, the reader gets the sense that they were a stand-in for the "machine" of modern geopolitics.

You might imagine why this story came to mind recently, though I read it some time ago, and why it feels especially relevant today.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We're the names of the combatant states the same?  (I.e. were there still an Egypt, Jordan, Lebanon, Israel, etc..?)  Can you be more specific about when you likely read this?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for asking. I'm sorry to say that I do not recall any more than what I already shared.